# Array to Image conversion

Tags: python, image

I've been struggling for hours now with this tiny problem.
I've been trying to do some image modification. Here is the code snipet :

```js
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#Conversion image array
img = Image.open('lena.jpg')
array = np.array(img)

def niv_de_gris(img):

    height = len(img)
    width = len(img[0])
    
    #Creation tableau vide
    new_img = ([[[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(width)] for k in range(height)])

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            m = np.mean(img[i][j])
            for k in range(3):
                new_img[i][j][k] = int(m)

    return np.array(new_img)

array_gris = niv_de_gris(array)
img_gris = Image.fromarray(array_gris)  #problem is here !!
```

the first conversion works perfectly fine : it takes an image an converts it into an array. The program runs flowlessly, the image modification works, it sends me back an array of the image converted in gray levels.

Yet when I want to convert this array into an image to `.show()` it, i get this error :

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8dEB.png)

Can anybody help me figure this out pls?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array to PIL may need to ensure `pixel values are not 0-1 but 0-255`, `type is unit8` and then define the `mode as 'RGB'`.

Try using -

```
array_gris = niv_de_gris(array) * 255  #Skip this step if pixels are 0-255 already
array_gris = array_gris.astype(np.uint8)
img_gris = Image.fromarray(array_gris, mode='RGB')
```

That worked for me on a random image that I choose. Depending on the function and the image, I believe the only real important step is to ensure they are legit pixel values and that type is uint8.

Comment: Worked fine, just had to remove the "model" keyword which wasn't accepted ! Thx a lot !

Comment: Oh it’s supposed to be mode. Fixed